# Filters function instead of SQL selects using EJB's/JPA

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

i hava one doubte, i hoppe someone can give-me some light. Normaly i do my projects using JSF and EJB/JPA, so, when ai need to get some data, filtered, from database i have two ways to do it:

- Sending the parameters of the query to an sql stored procedure, ou some query and reetrieve the results.

  or
- Get the list of all data, and create some functions that recive the list of entities end retrive de filtered list, according some criteria.

Something like:

```
//on managed bean
...
List<Person> listPersons = personFacade.findAll();

return filterByName(filterByAge(filterBySomething(listPersons )));
```

For me is more easy do it by the second option, but im not sure if it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you define your "filter" using the Java Persistence Query Language and let the JPA container do its work...

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html

JPQL is transformed into SQL, so the database is doing the work and only the filtered entity beans are returned to the EJB layer of your application.

Instead, if you filter them later on, the entire database table has to be loaded into memory first. So an entity bean will be created for every record only to throw it away shortly afterwards because its filtered out of your list.